# On topology of p-adic numbers.

Tags: nt.number-theory

This may be a stupid question.But I am stuck with it.Is Q_p(the p-adic) connected under the usual topology?I was confounded with this problem while trying to construct a counter-example related to my master's thesis.

Comment: Both Wikipedia and Google know the answer to this (very elementary) question. If you don't find it there or by yourself, you should try http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is about as far from being connected as possible: it's totally disconnected - the maximal connected subsets are points.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a punctured Cantor set, meaning that it is homeomorphic to a Cantor set minus one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any non-empty open can be written as a disjoint union of opens ; for example
$\mathbb{Z}_p=\cup(a+p\mathbb{Z}_p)$ where $a$ runs through $\{0...(p-1)\}$. Those spaces are said totally disconnected.

Comment: actually this happens for any topological group admitting a base of neighborhoods given by subgroups